# How to express a=8 versus b=4?

Tags: inequality

I want to know how to express in English a and b.

a is larger(=greater, bigger) than b as four. (right?)

b is smaller(=less) than a as four. (right?)

thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Do you want to say $a$ is larger than $b$ by 4?  This means $a-b=4$, so 9 is larger than 5 by 4. You can also say 9 is 4 larger than 5, or 9 is larger by 4 than 5.

Comment: a is larger than b **by** four (this means, a is larger than b and a minus b is 4)

b is smaller than a **_by_** four, not _as_ four.

Comment: Thanks. I've just knew that I have to  use 'by' instead of 'as'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For positive numbers, "greater than", "larger than", "bigger than" are pretty much interchangeable, as are "less than" and "smaller than". In a formal context such as a paper, you're more likely to see "greater than" and "less than".

When negative numbers could be involved, use "greater than" or "less than", not "larger", "bigger", "smaller", as the "size" of a number could refer to its absolute value.

Answer (score 2):

You can say `a is larger than b` or `a is larger than 4` or a is larger than b, which is 4`.

Instead of `larger`, `greater` or `bigger` could be used.

Answer (score 2):

$8$ is larger than $4$. $8$ is greater than $4$.

$4$ is smaller than $8$. $4$ is less than $8$.

Comment: No!!!  4 is less than 8, not "lesser".

Comment: Thanks. I've just knew that I have to  use 'by' instead of 'as'.

Answer (score 2):

The terminology I know, is "(strictly) greater than" for $>$ and "(strictly) less than" for $<$.